# Why is $I+T$ invertible for this rank-one operator $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am working with the following lemma given in the book Topics in Banach Spaces Theory:

Let ${(x_n)}_{n=1}^{\infty}$  be a basic sequence in Banach Space $X$. Suppose that there exists a linear functinal $x^{\ast} \in X^{\ast} $ such that $x^{\ast}(x_n)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. If $u\notin [x_n]$ then the sequence ${(x_n +u)}_{n=1}^{\infty }$ is basic.

This is the proof:

Since $u\notin [x_n]$, without loss of generality we can assume $x^{\ast}(u)=0$. Let $T:X\to X$ given by  $\:T(x)=x^{\ast}(x)u$. Then $I_X+T$ is invertible with inverse $I_X-T$. Since $(I_X+T)(x_n)=x_n+u$, the sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{x_n+u\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are congruent, hence $\{x_n+u\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is basic.

I don't understand why $I_x+T$ is invertible. According to the Theorem about the existence of the inverse operator (which can be found on the page 329 of [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105909697/Topics%20in%20Banach%20Space%20Theory.pdf) book) if $\lVert I_X-(I_X+T)\lVert = \lVert T\lVert<1$ then we are guranteed the existce of the inverse and $${(I_x+T)}^{-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} [I_X+ (-T)+ {(-T)}^2+\dots+ {(-T)}^n ]$$
Based on our assumption that  $x^{\ast}(u)=0$ then $$T^2(x)=T(T(x))=T(x^{\ast}(x)u)=x^{\ast}(x^{\ast}(x)u)u=x^{\ast}(x)x^{\ast}(u)u=0$$ and thus ${(-T)}^2$=0. Hence we would have $T^3=T(T^2)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \dots T^n=0$ and therefore
$${(I_x+T)}^{-1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} [I_X+ (-T)]=I_X-T$$
If I knew that $\lVert T\lVert<1$ then everything is ok, but why is it so?

Comment: Explicitly check that $I+T$ has inverse $I-T$ by verifying that $ (I+T) \circ (I-T)(x)= (I-T)\circ (I+T) (x) = x$ for all $x\in X.$

Comment: I checked according to your suggestion and indeed it turns out that   \begin{align*}[(I+T)(I-T)](x)&=[I\circ I-I\circ T+T\circ I-T\circ T](x)\\&=I(I(x))-I(T(x))+T(I(x))-T(T(x))\\&=x-x^{\ast}(x)u+x^{\ast}(x)u-0\\&=x \end{align*} which shows that $I-T$ is the inverse of $I+T$.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to stay inside the frame of Theorem about the existence of the inverse operator. And in my understanding the sufficient condition to do that, in this case, is having guaranteed that $\lVert T \lVert<1$. But still it is clear that $I+T$ and $I-T$ are inverse functions of each-other. –

Answer (score 1):

The operator $I+T$ is a rank-one perturbation of identity, displacement along $u$. Importantly, the amount of displacement is constant on every line parallel to $u$; this allows us to return to original position by applying the opposite displacement. Here's this statement in greater generality, for possible nonlinear operators (in a space over field $\mathbb K$).

*If $f:X\to \mathbb K$ is such that $f(x+tu)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $t\in\mathbb K$, then the maps $x\mapsto x\pm f(x)u$ are inverses of each other.*

Indeed,
$$(x+f(x)u)-f(x+f(x) u )u = (x+f(x)u)-f(x)u  =x$$

Comment: Your suggestion is really helpfull and sense-making. I am using this lemma in my Master Thesis so I need to cite every result which I will be using. Can you tell me a source (book/article) where I can find the result that you have stated?